# converting date from one given format to another

Tags: javascript, time

I have date in this format ,

```
Tue Sep 04 2018 05:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time).
```

I need to convert it to this format

```
2018-12-16T00:00:00.000Z
```

If i store the first one in a variable and try `x.toISOString()`, it throws an error.

What should be the correct method to get this done ?

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: x.toISOString is not a function

Comment: x should be a valid date format to be able to convert it to ISO string. Attached an answer for your reference

Comment: you can easily parse your date string and construct your own new string in your arbitrary format.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toISOString();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Date in ISO</button>

<div id="date"></div>
```